# Target WSGI cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

How to solve these errors ? Thank you very much for your help.

- [Sat Apr 24 06:58:37.647922 2021] [:error] [pid 1430] [remote 172.31.12.184:248] mod_wsgi (pid=1430): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/greatkart/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
- [Sat Apr 24 06:58:37.648302 2021] [:error] [pid 1430] [remote 172.31.12.184:248]   File "/opt/python/current/app/greatkart/settings.py", line 120, in
- [Sat Apr 24 06:58:37.648305 2021] [:error] [pid 1430] [remote 172.31.12.184:248]     'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'greatkart.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

settings.py

```
# Database Configuration
if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }
```

requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.2.10
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
Django==3.1
django-admin-honeypot==1.1.0
django-admin-thumbnails==0.2.5
django-session-timeout==0.1.0
idna==2.10
Pillow==8.2.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
python-decouple==3.4
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.25.1
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
urllib3==1.26.3
```

db-migrate.config

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: greatkart.settings
```

django.config

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python": 
    WSGIPath: "greatkart/wsgi.py"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "static/"
```

config.yml

```
branch-defaults:
  main:
    environment: django-env-4
    group_suffix: null
environment-defaults:
  django-env:
    branch: null
    repository: null
  seast-kart-env:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: django-tutorial-4
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: aws-eb
  default_platform: Python 3.6
  default_region: us-west-2
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

Edit :
Full Traceback

```
[Fri Apr 23 13:21:43.405667 2021] [suexec:notice] [pid 3188] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Apr 23 13:21:43.420808 2021] [http2:warn] [pid 3188] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Fri Apr 23 13:21:43.420820 2021] [http2:warn] [pid 3188] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Fri Apr 23 13:21:43.421241 2021] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 3188] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Apr 23 13:21:43.421281 2021] [:warn] [pid 3188] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.
[Fri Apr 23 13:21:43.421285 2021] [:warn] [pid 3188] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.12.
[Fri Apr 23 13:21:43.423065 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3188] AH00163: Apache/2.4.46 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 23 13:21:43.423081 2021] [core:notice] [pid 3188] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:18.244515 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3188] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:19.296214 2021] [suexec:notice] [pid 3418] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:19.310192 2021] [so:warn] [pid 3418] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:19.312609 2021] [http2:warn] [pid 3418] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:19.312621 2021] [http2:warn] [pid 3418] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:19.313166 2021] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 3418] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:19.313227 2021] [:warn] [pid 3418] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:19.313232 2021] [:warn] [pid 3418] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.12.
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:19.315504 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3418] AH00163: Apache/2.4.46 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:19.315522 2021] [core:notice] [pid 3418] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.687415 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=3423): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/greatkart/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.687467 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=3423): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/greatkart/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688631 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688694 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/current/app/greatkart/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688699 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688706 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688710 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688715 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688719 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688725 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688733 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     self._setup(name)
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688740 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688743 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688748 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688752 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688757 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688760 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688765 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688770 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688775 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688781 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688786 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688791 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 781, in get_code
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688796 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 741, in source_to_code
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688801 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688815 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/current/app/greatkart/settings.py", line 33
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688824 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     \xc2\xb2
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688838 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     ^
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:22.688845 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.691877 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40] mod_wsgi (pid=3423): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/greatkart/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.691926 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40] mod_wsgi (pid=3423): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/greatkart/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692096 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692152 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]   File "/opt/python/current/app/greatkart/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692157 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692163 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692167 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692172 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692176 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692181 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692193 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]     self._setup(name)
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692199 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692202 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692207 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692211 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692216 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692219 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692224 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692229 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692234 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692239 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692244 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692249 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 781, in get_code
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692259 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 741, in source_to_code
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692264 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692278 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]   File "/opt/python/current/app/greatkart/settings.py", line 33
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692288 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]     \xc2\xb2
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692304 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40]     ^
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:23.692311 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40] SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
[Fri Apr 23 13:22:24.695493 2021] [:error] [pid 3423] [remote 127.0.0.1:40] mod_wsgi (pid=3423): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/greatkart/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
```

Edit 2
Database config :
[Database config in AWS EB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06XUT.png)

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Is the error `KeyError: RDS_HOSTNAME`? If not then what?

Comment: I edited the first message to put the full traceback, thank you.

`RDS_HOSTNAME` seems to be the error but I don't know why, this key seems to be used in many tutorials about deploying Django app on AWS

Comment: Did you add the database to your environment? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html

Comment: [see picture Edit : 2] 
I've set these variables in my environment propery 
```SECRET_KEY```
```DEBUG```
```ENGINE```
```EMAIL_HOST```
```EMAIL_PORT```
```EMAIL_HOST_USER```
```EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD```
```EMAIL_USE_TLS```

But I haven't  set ```RDS_DB_NAME```
```RDS_USERNAME```
```RDS_PASSWORD```
```RDS_HOSTNAME```
```RDS_PORT```
I don't know what I should set them to

Comment: The immediate problem (at least in the edited posting) is the complaint `File "/opt/python/current/app/greatkart/settings.py", line 33` about `\xc2\xb2` being an invalid character in identifier. So take a look at the file `/opt/python/current/app/greatkart/settings.py`. Figure out what installed it (probably you) and why whatever installed it wrote something invalid on line 33. In any case, this has nothing to do with Git (and probably nothing to do with most of the other tags listed either). See also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/